# Returning a single sum from 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries to get a *sum* and I would like to combine them into a single select query if possible noting they have different field names in the *where* clause.

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Stocking_Count), 0)
FROM Fish_Stocking
WHERE fish_id = 'B2017-1' 
  AND tank_id = 'H A01' 
  AND Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' 
  AND stocking_date <= '2017-03-28'

SELECT ISNULL(SUM(NO_FISH_SWUM_OFF), 0)
FROM Swim_Thru
WHERE Dest_fish_id = 'B2017-1' 
  AND Dest_tank_id = 'H A01' 
  AND Dest_Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' 
  AND date_swim_thru <= '2017-03-28'
```

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You can check my below working answer..

Answer (score 0):

as subqueries

```
 select 
     (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Stocking_Count),0)
    FROM Fish_Stocking
    where fish_id = 'B2017-1' and tank_id = 'H A01' and
          Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' and stocking_date <= '2017-03-28') [Field1],

    ( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(NO_FISH_SWUM_OFF),0)
    FROM Swim_Thru
    where Dest_fish_id = 'B2017-1' and Dest_tank_id = 'H A01' and
          Dest_Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' and date_swim_thru <= '2017-03-28') [Field2]
```

Comment: Also works but returns in 2 fields as per the code so again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: yes because i assumed you were after of two results in 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are trying which can be accomplished with `UNION ALL` as below.

*NOTE*: I have also changed `ISNULL(SUM(Stocking_Count),0)` to `SUM(ISNULL(Stocking_Count, 0))`.

```
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM (
    (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Stocking_Count, 0)) as Total
    FROM Fish_Stocking
    where fish_id = 'B2017-1' and tank_id = 'H A01' and
          Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' and stocking_date <= '2017-03-28')

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(NO_FISH_SWUM_OFF, 0)) as Total
    FROM Swim_Thru
    where Dest_fish_id = 'B2017-1' and Dest_tank_id = 'H A01' and
          Dest_Date_Assigned = '2017-02-02' and date_swim_thru <= '2017-03-28')

) Net
```

Comment: Im sum(isnull returns a null while isnull(sum doesn't so in c# it causes an error but in c++ it doesn't